# Intersection between a plane and a curve

Tags: calculus

> Find the point(s) at which the following plane and curve intersect.
>
> The plane: $$3x+4y-12z=0.$$  The curve $$r(t)=\langle 3\cos t,3\sin
> > t,\cos{t} \rangle; 0≤t≤2\pi.$$

I started out by plugging $$x=3\cos t, y=3\sin t, z=\cos t$$ into the equation of the plane and simplified.

I got down to $$\tan(t)=\frac{1}{4}.$$

Not sure how to proceed to come up with the exact answer.

Answer (score 3):

You got the right answer in which $$t^*=\arctan(1/4)$$ But, regarding to the interval we 're given, there is another point which is: $$t^{**}=t^*+\pi$$
The finial step seems to be that putting $t^*$ and $t^{**}$ into $\textbf{r}(t)$ so we have two points in $\mathbb R^3$ as follows: $$\textbf{r}(t^*)=\langle 3\cos(t^*),3\sin(t^*),\cos(t^*)\rangle,~~\textbf{r}(t^{**})=\langle 3\cos(t^{**}),3\sin(t^*),\cos(t^{**})\rangle$$

[image]

Comment: Excellent illustration (and answer)! $\quad \overset{\small \star_{\,}>\star}{\smile}$

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks Amy. :) I 've started the new with your answers. Have a great day ahead. :)

Comment: Ya but I was eager to see the site and yours, my friend. :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan t = \frac{1}{4} \leftrightarrow \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{4} = t$$

Now, restricted to the interval 
$$[0, 2\pi]$$
The period of the tangent function is pi, so it repeats every $$\pi n$$
intervals. Therefore...
$$t = \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{4} + \pi n$$

Comment: You can make the 'if and only if' symbol using \Leftrightarrow in LaTeX. It looks a little better.